# Is there a way to track point after applying transformations with openGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I am trying to find a way to track an arbitrary point in x,y,z after applying transformations.

Something like this

```
 glTranslated(0,2,4);
 glScaled(3,4,5);
 glTranslated(2,4,5);
 glRotated(24,0,1,0);
 point = Point(3,4,2)


 printf ("the point is now in %f,%f and %f",point.x,point.y,point.z);
```

I am using C with openGL 2.

Comment: Sure, just apply the same transformation to the point.

Comment: You can record all the transformations in a single matrix, and then access that to find the new location of any original point.

Comment: [`gluProject`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluProject.xml)?

Comment: Might be a good time to look at the glm library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to replicate how OpenGL builds and combines your matrices, the easiest approach is probably to get the current matrix:

```
GLfloat mat[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mat);
```

Then you can multiply this matrix with the points you want to transform. Remember that OpenGL stores matrices in column major order. So to apply it to a point `(x, y, z)`, the multiplication would be:

```
xNew = mat[0] * x + mat[4] * y + mat[8] * z + mat[12];
yNew = mat[1] * x + mat[5] * y + mat[9] * z + mat[13];
zNew = mat[2] * x + mat[6] * y + mat[10] * z + mat[14];
```